# Better method to avoid UI hang while taking view screenshot in IOS .?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, nsdata

I started search on "How to take a screenshot programmatically in IOS".

Found Results :

- Option 1 : `renderInContext`
- Option 2 : `drawViewHierarchyInRect` (not applicable for my case)

To avoid drawing and loading views every time in `collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath`,

I am:

- taking screenshots of number of invisible custom views,
- saving its screenshots in local directory,
- loading image from local directory in `UICollectionview` cells.

The problem here is when I make a screenshot of UIView using `[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]` in main thread, it makes UI freeze for a while.

Is there any alternate to avoid?

I tried `dispatch_async` but it's not working.

As an alternative, I tried saving drawn view as data using `NSKeyedArchiver`,
My custom view saved as data in Local Directory by `writeToFile : atomically` option.

Later I used `NSKeyedUnArchiver` to extract the view from Data saved in Local Directory.

Here the issue is context drawn in (drawInRect) Custom Views are not coming.

Only view properties like its frame, label and text are coming when view loaded from unarchived data.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.